# Deactivate Gutenberg tips forever - not Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I like Gutenberg a lot, however, the tips at the beginning of each page load
drives me mad. I would like to disable the nagging tips forever and ever via code.

Please don't post "Disable Gutenberg" plugin, I've already seen that. I want to do it via a couple of lines of code in my theme.

There must be a hook, but I couldn't find it.
Thanks for a hint.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

### Update #1:

After asking from  @leymannx I checked how these settings are stored.
It turned out that settings are not permanent, they are saved in the browser as `localStorage`.

```
key: WP_DATA_USER_{id}:
value: {
    "core/nux":{
        "preferences":{
            "areTipsEnabled":false,
            "dismissedTips":{}
        }
    },
    //"core/edit-post"
    //...
```

### Update #2:

Gutenberg tips can be disabled by using `dispatch('core/nux').disableTips()` ([NUX package](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/nux/README.md#disabling-and-enabling-tips)) and action hook `enqueue_block_editor_assets`.

file *functions.php*:

```
function se334561_editor_tips() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'se334561-js',
        // --- to use in plugin ---
        // plugins_url('/disable-tips.js', __FILE__),
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/disable-tips.js',
        array('wp-blocks')
    );
}
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'se334561_editor_tips');
```

file *disable-tips.js*:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var isVisible = wp.data.select('core/nux').areTipsEnabled()
    if (isVisible) {
        wp.data.dispatch('core/nux').disableTips();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this globally for every user? Is there a way to configure this per code as well? So that when I ship a plugin to a client it deactivates the tips when this plugin gets activated?

Comment: @leymannx These are individual settings for each user.

Comment: If it’s an option able checkbox in the admin area they’ll be away to toggle it for all as the values got to be stored somewhere you should in code be able to set that value for all users on init or something, try to find where it stores that value in the DB

Comment: @leymannx This would require additional code (js + php) which, after changing `areTipsEnabled`, writes the state to DB and restores it when the user logs in.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I knew the options panel before, and "yes, it is not stored permanently". That's exactly what I'm looking for. Disable it permanently.

Comment: @user3135691 I updated answer

Comment: That is awesome, I'll try it out tomorrow and check the answer if it works. Thank you!

Comment: This code works in a theme (functions.php). I have also started to build it in a plugin, but for some reason I can't get to load the js in the editor via plugin. Thanks for your help so far. Really great.

Comment: @user3135691 In plugin file replace `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/disable-tips.js'`  with `plugins_url('/disable-tips.js', __FILE__)`.

Comment: I got it working - that is reallllyyy awesome - thank you man. @everyone - feel free to grab the latest working version of the plugin here: https://bitbucket.org/rgmarketing/disable-gutenberg-tips-not-gutenberg/src

Answer (score 2):

As @nmr found out this seems to be stored browser-wise only. Though I found a workaround to simply hide it via CSS. Quick and dirty.

#### `functions.php`:

```
// Add backend styles for Gutenberg.
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'gutenberg_editor_assets');

function gutenberg_editor_assets() {
  // Load the theme styles within Gutenberg.
  wp_enqueue_style('my-gutenberg-editor-styles', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/gutenberg-editor-styles.css'), FALSE);
}
```

#### `assets/gutenberg-editor-styles.css`:

```
.components-popover.nux-dot-tip {
  display: none !important;
}
```

---

Source: [Creating theme editor styles for Gutenberg](https://florianbrinkmann.com/en/4544/editor-styles-gutenberg/)

Comment: Yes, this solution also came to my mind but as you have said: it's quick 'n dirty. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Small plugin that should fix it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-welcome-messages-and-tips/

The relevant part of the code is:

```
<style>
    /* disable tips */
    .wp-admin .components-popover.nux-dot-tip {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>

<script>
    /* disable welcome message */
    window.onload = function(){
        wp.data && wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isFeatureActive( 'welcomeGuide' ) && wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleFeature( 'welcomeGuide' );
    };
</script>
```